# "If not div" onclick event not including children divs

Tags: javascript

Using vanilla JS, I'm trying to create an off click - as in, if the body is clicked and it is not a certain element that is clicked, close that element.

However, it works when you click the specified element (it doesn't close), but it fires the event when you click any of that element's child nodes. I'd like the if statement to include any child nodes of that parent element, as well as the parent node itself.

HTML:

```
<ul id="NavSocial-target" class="Nav_social">
    <li class="Nav_social_item">Facebook</li>
    <li class="Nav_social_item">Twitter</li>
    <li class="Nav_social_item">Google</li>
</ul>

<ul class="Nav_options FlexList">
    <li class="Nav_options_item FlexList_item" id="NavSocial-trigger">Social</li>
    <li class="Nav_options_item FlexList_item">Curr/Lang</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
this.triggerDOM =  document.getElementById('NavSocial-trigger');
this.targetDOM =  document.getElementById('NavSocial-target');

// If not list item that triggers model && if not model itself
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick = (e) => {
    if(e.target !== this.triggerDOM && e.target !== this.targetDOM){
        this.removeClass();
    }  
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume `this.triggerDOM` is the element you want to ignore. You need to see if the click *passed through* the element, with a loop:

```
this.triggerDOM =  document.getElementById('NavSocial-trigger');
// ...
document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
    var element = e.target;
    while (element && element !== document.body) {
        if (element === this.triggerDOM) {
            // It was a click in `this.triggerDOM` or one of its
            // children; ignore it
            return;
        }
        element = element.parentNode;
    }
    // It wasn't a click anywhere in `this.triggerDOM`
    this.removeClass();
}, false);
```

Side notes on the above:

- `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` is just a long way to write `document.body` :-)
- Using `onclick` doesn't play nicely with others; use `addEventListener` (or `attachEvent` on IE8 and earlier, if you still need to support seriously obsolete browsers).
- Arrow functions accepting a single argument don't need `()` around the argument list (though of course it's fine to have them there if you prefer the style).

---

Working example:

```js
this.triggerDOM = document.getElementById('NavSocial-trigger');
// ...
document.body.addEventListener("click", e => {
  var element = e.target;
  while (element && element !== document.body) {
    if (element === this.triggerDOM) {
      // It was a click in `this.triggerDOM` or one of its
      // children; ignore it
      return;
    }
    element = element.parentNode;
  }
  // It wasn't a click anywhere in `this.triggerDOM`
  this.triggerDOM.parentNode.removeChild(this.triggerDOM);
}, false);
```

```css
#NavSocial-trigger {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #dd0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Note the really deep nesting -->
<div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div><div>
  Click
  <div>
    anywhere
    <div>
      on
      <div>
        this
        <div>
          page
          <div>
            except
            <div id="NavSocial-trigger">
              here
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll give this a go. Does it not have any performance repercussions traversing through the entire DOM?

Comment: @DorianHuxley: The above *doesn't* traverse the entire DOM. It traverses the ancestry of the clicked element (from it to its parent to its parent until we reach `body`). Even if you had an element nested 1,000 deep (which you don't), the loop would complete near-instantaneously, and certainly before a human could detect a delay.

Comment: @DorianHuxley: I seem to have forgotten a **really important line of code** above: `element = element.parentNode`. I've added it now.

Comment: Thanks, still a bit unsure as to where to call the this.removeClass() function

Comment: I'm trying to call a particular function if it is not the particular node. I've changed the code to this:
            while (element && element !== document.body) {
                if (element === this.triggerDOM || element == this.targetDOM) {
                    stopEvent = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (!stopEvent) {
                this.removeClass();
            }

But it's crashing the page..

Comment: @DorianHuxley: I assume you want to call it if the click wasn't anywhere in `this.triggerDOM`, right? So you'd put it after the `// It wasn't a click anywhere in this.triggerDOM` comment. In the live example, I removed the element there, but that was just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: @DorianHuxley: There are two paths out of the click handler above; both are clearly commented to indicate what condition exists at that moment.

Comment: Please see edit. Unfortunately, this does crash the page

Comment: @DorianHuxley: No, it does not "crash the page." See the live example in the answer. Then look at how you've appled that, and see where things have gone wrong. There's clearly something different in the page you say crashes. It is *not* the code above.